# Silent termination of process while local debugging C# Azure Function

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, debug-symbols, azure-functions-core-tools

While debugging (F5) in VS Code, the integrated terminal would should a flurry of operations under Task: Build which would be completed successfully and then even proceed to Task - host start. But instead of halting the process and providing the invocation URL, the Task-host start would silently terminate. ANd even this behaviour was not consistent because on occassion, it would "Task - host start" would actually do its job and provide the invocation URL. However the breakpoint is not hit on the invocation of the function and I see in the Breakpoints lane that it changes from a red dot to a hollow white dot and in the breakpoint pane on the debug , on hovering over the breakpoint, VS code says "No symbols have been loaded for this document"

Answer (score 0):

The issue was tracked to the Azure Functions core tool. So previously when I was developing against .net core 2.2, I had downloaded v2 of the Azure Functions core tool via choco. So when I moved to .net core 3.0, I had installed v3 of the Azure Functions core tool via npm. But during debugging instead of picking up v3, it used to pick up v2 of the Azure Functions core tools.

> Executing task: func host start <

```
              %%%%%%
             %%%%%%
        @   %%%%%%    @
      @@   %%%%%%      @@
   @@@    %%%%%%%%%%%    @@@
 @@      %%%%%%%%%%        @@
   @@         %%%%       @@
     @@      %%%       @@
       @@    %%      @@
            %%
            %
```

Azure Functions Core Tools (**2.7.1948** Commit hash: 29a0626ded3ae99c4111f66763f27bb9fb564103)
Function Runtime Version: **2.0.12888.0**

So once v2 was uninstalled via choco, the debugging process worked as expected.

to Eric Jizba and Jeff Holan for helping me out here.